# Do I need to put multiple Id's in a table if I want to get 3 different Id's(with other info) from another table?

Tags: sql, database-design, foreign-keys, many-to-many

I am learning about SQL and tables, foreign keys, etc. To try it instead of only learning it I created 2 tables:

Table 1: `Team`:

[image: Team table]

Table 2: `Karakter` (that is "character" in Dutch)

[image: Karakter table]

A team has an Id (`TeamId`), UserId (`GebruikerId`, this is not important for now), name (`Teamnaam`) and CharacterId (`KarakterId`).

I want a team to exist of 3 characters (`karakters`), and I know I can find character via foreign keys, but sins I want 3 characters and not only 1 I was wondering if in my table TeamI need to put KarakterId1, KarakterId2, KarakterId3?

Or do you usually do this in another simpler way that I don't know of (Because I can not find it)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

That's a many-to-many relationship between teams and characters: where one team has several characters, and a given character may belong to more than one team.

A normalized design implies creating a third table, called a bridge table, to represent that relationship, with one row for each team/character tuple, and foreign key constraints the reference the parent tables.

```
create table teams (
    team_id int primary key,
    user_id int not null,
    name varchar(50)
);

create table characters (
    character_id int primary key,
    name varchar(50)
);

create table team_characters (
    team_id int references teams(team_id),
    character_id int references characters(character_id),
    primary key (team_id, character_id)
);
```

Comment: And should I put into the team_characters table 3 times characterId? Or how should it otherwise know it has to has 3 characters in it?

Comment: @LardinoisJ: if a team has 3 characters, that means 3 rows in the bridge table, with the same `team_id` and 3 different `character_id`s.

Answer (score 0):

Precisely verbalizing the constraint in natural language usually reveals the correct solution. Here are two possible examples, there can be more.

---

- Each karakter *may be* in *more than one* team;
  for each team: *more than one* karakter *may be* in that team.

```
karakter {K}
      PK {K}


team {T}
  PK {T}


team_karakter {T, K}
           PK {T, K}

          FK1 {K} REFERENCES karakter {K}
          FK2 {T} REFERENCES team     {T}
```

---

- Each karakter *may be* in *more than one* team;
  for each team: *exactly three* karakters *are* in that team.

```
karakter {K}
      PK {K}


team {T, K1, K2, K3}
  PK {T}

 FK1 {K1} REFERENCES karakter {K}
 FK2 {K2} REFERENCES karakter {K}
 FK3 {K3} REFERENCES karakter {K}

 CHECK ((K1 <> K2) AND (K1 <> K3) AND (K2 <> K3))
```

Note:

```
All attributes (columns) NOT NULL

PK = Primary Key
FK = Foreign Key
```